# Why were two very similar questions posted by possibly the same user?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, cross-posting

This morning I filtered for the Java tag and found the two questions in the picture below as the first result:

[image]

Could these be bots? Maybe these are the same user, but why should one post the same question twice, trying to make it look different by changing some words? I saw the first one was migrated from SO, but it still is another account though.

Question 1: [Validate particular id's depending on what process type is coming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154039/validate-particular-ids-depending-on-what-process-type-is-coming)

Question 2: [Validate id's depending on process type](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154051/validate-ids-depending-on-process-type)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I originally saw the CR version and later saw the SO one. I flagged the latter for migration here, but since the code wasn't exactly the same, I decided not to merge the answers into one and delete the other.

I'm not sure why the user posted with different accounts, but since the SO one wasn't also created on here, I cannot determine if they're really from the same person.  Until then, I'll keep the SO one closed as duplicate.